# Storybook doesn't understand import on demand for antd components

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, antd, storybook

I have followed [instructions](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) here to get **antd** working fine with **CRA**. But while using it from **storybook**, I was getting an **error** as:

> Build fails against a mixin with message Inline JavaScript is not
> enabled. Is it set in your options?

I had **fixed** that following suggestions on an issue I raised [here](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/3949).

Now, **storybook** understands **antd** **but not importing components on demand**. Is babel has to be configured separately for storybook?

**1**. On using `import { Button } from "antd";`
I get this:

[image]

**2**. On using

```
import Button from "antd/lib/button";
import "antd/lib/button/style";
```

I get:

[image]

> Storybook version: "@storybook/react": "^3.4.8"
>
> Dependency: "antd": "^3.7.3"

I have been stuck (again) with this for quite long hours googling things, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried ```import { Button } from "antd"; import "antd/lib/button/style";
```` ?

Answer (score 7):

Using Storybook 4, you can create a **webpack.config.js** file in the **.storybook** directory with the following configuration:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                test: /\.js$/,
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/react"],
                    plugins: [
                        ['import', {libraryName: "antd", style: true}]
                    ]
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loaders: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "less-loader",

                        options: {
                            modifyVars: {"@primary-color": "#d8df19"},
                            javascriptEnabled: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Note that the above snippet includes a style overwriting of the primary button color in antd. I figured, you might want to eventually edit the default theme so you can remove that line in case you do not intend to do so.

You can now import the Button component in Storybook using:

```
import {Button} from "antd";
```

without having to also import the style file.

Comment: How does the `Button` style magically appear without being imported by the developer?

Comment: @vsync the styles for `Button` are being imported by [babel_plugin_import](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import)

```import { Button } from 'antd';
ReactDOM.render(<Button>xxxx</Button>);

 ----->     
var _button = require('antd/lib/button');
ReactDOM.render(<_button>xxxx</_button>);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [AntD Advanced-Guides for React](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Advanced-Guides) and storybook v5 create `.storybook/webpack.config.js` with the following:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {

  config.module.rules.push({
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      options: {
          presets: ['@babel/react'],
          plugins: [
              ['import', {
                libraryName: 'antd',
                libraryDirectory: 'es',
                style: true
              }]
          ]
      },
  });

  config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
              loader: 'less-loader',
              options: {
                  modifyVars: {'@primary-color': '#f00'},
                  javascriptEnabled: true
              }
          }
      ],
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*antd/
      ]
  });

  return config;
};
```

Then you can use `import { Button } from 'antd'` to import antd components.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using storybook with antd and i got it to play nice, by using this config in my webpack.config.js file in the .storybook folder:

```
const { injectBabelPlugin } = require('react-app-rewired');
const path = require("path");

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
config = injectBabelPlugin(
['import', { libraryName: 'antd', libraryDirectory: 'es', style: 'css' }],
config,
);



config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", ],
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
  })


return config;
};
```