# Use antd for React together with Storybook v5

Tags: reactjs, antd, storybook

Now, I am stuck for several hours trying to make Storybook work with antd in my new React application (created with `create-react-app`), without success.

Whatever I do, Storybook does not take the styling of antd.

For example, I created a menu item with antd:

`menuNav.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import {Menu} from 'antd';
import "antd/dist/antd.less";


const MenuNav = () => {
    return (
        <Menu mode="horizontal">
            <Menu.Item key="menu1">
                This is my menu title
            </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
    )
}

export default MenuNav;
```

But the result looks like this, no styling at all, but a list:

[image]

And as you can see here, it understands that the menu is created by the UI library, but there is no antd styling applied:

[image]

This is the story file of `MenuNav`, `3-Menu.stories.js`:

```
import React from "react";

import MenuNav from '../components/MenuNav';

export default {
    title: "MenuNav",
    component: MenuNav,
};

export const Text = () => <MenuNav></MenuNav>
```

I already tried to add a `config.js` inside `./storybook` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655667/storybook-and-antdesign-components-how-to-set-up-with-cra-typescript), with no success. Furthermore, I tried adding a `webpack.config.js` in the same directory as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679614/storybook-doesnt-understand-import-on-demand-for-antd-components/53490766#53490766), same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try adding `@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';` to your applications main file, let say `index.css` which for example is placed in `src` folder and then add `import '../src/index.css';` to `.storybook/preview.js`
`